# jQuery Mobile themes - Where to get them? Re-purpose jQTouch themes?

Tags: jquery, themes, jquery-mobile, jqtouch

Where can I find themes for jQuery Mobile (JQM) that go beyond the packaged five themes & color variations of them?

Either cross device or device specific ones, for example

- iphone / apple style
- android specific

What is the effort to re-purpose for example the jQTouch apple theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ThemeRoller for jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) to easily create your own theme.

Comment: [ThemeRoller for jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) is out now. You might want to update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use iOS-inspired theme for jQuery Mobile.

You can get here:

https://github.com/taitems/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme

git clone git://github.com/taitems/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme.git

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answers you can find an android inspired jQuery Mobile design here:

http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/

Comes with dark/light and 5 colors.